# Intellisense not working with packages installed with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I can't see any methods inside a package when installing it with npm.

[image: What I see]

[image: What I expect]

Anyone knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `validator.validator`?

Comment: Did not work also.